# Export Datatable to excel using closedXML exports data with HTML tags and not readable format

Tags: export-to-excel, closedxml

I am trying to export datatable to excel. I am using closedXML. My datatable contains HTML tags . Export excel is exporting data with HTML tags and not with readable format.
My code is as below

```
    public static MemoryStream ConvertDataTableToExcel(DataTable dt, string name, bool addColumnNames = true)
    {
                var stream = new MemoryStream();
                if (dt != null)
                {
                    using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
                    {
                        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add(name);
                        var rowno = 1;
                        var colno = 1;
    
                        if (addColumnNames)
                        {
                            //get column list and add as first row
                            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                            {
                                worksheet.Cell(rowno, colno).Value = StripHTML(column.ColumnName);
                                colno++;
                            }
                        }
    
                        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            ++rowno;
                            colno = 1;
                            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                            {
                                worksheet.Cell(rowno, colno).Value=(dr[column.ColumnName].ToString());
                                ++colno;
                            }
                        }workbook.SaveAs(stream);
                    }
                }
                return stream;
    }
```

My current output in excel cell is:

````
<ol start="6"><li>In observing the inventory, you should check:<ol type="a"><li>From reported counts to stock</li><li>From stock to reported counts</li><li>Identity of inventory items.</li></ol></li><ol>```

My expected output is :

6.In observing the inventory, you should check:
  a.From reported counts to stock
  b.From stock to reported counts
  c.Identity of inventory items.
````

Comment: Converting HTML to Excel formatting is a library unto itself. The question is also a bit unclear as written. If that is not what you are asking for, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

ClosedXML doesn't support rendering HTML. It never has. I'm unsure why you even expect this to be supported.